# HTML 5 canvas element with GWT Query

Tags: jquery, gwt, gquery

Is it possible to use GWT-Query to use the HTML 5 canvas? I searched and found libraries to create charts easily with jQuery but since my app is using GWT I'm a bit in trouble.

This is what I found for jQuery:
http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update_to_jquery_visualize_accessible_charts_with_html5_from_designing_with/

I don't want to port such a thing in Java for GWT-Query, is there an alternative to creating nice data representation graphics under GWT?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well Google answered my question 10 months later :) They just integrated Canvas widget in GWT 2.2
Thank you Google.